# What program to use to open files? (gnome-open, gvfs-open, xdg-open, etc.)

Tags: linux, file-opening, xdg-open

I have a Java program that runs on Linux, and from within the program, I want to open files (e.g. PDF files) with the system's native viewer. There are various programs available for this purpose: gnome-open, gvfs-open, xdg-open, ...
Which one(s) should I use to cover as many Linux distributions as possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

xdg-open is the safest bet.  Not everyone will necessarily have gnome or gvfs installed.  xdg-open, on the other hand, is not tied to any desktop environment or toolkit.